# Bit-wise operations on ByteString

Tags: haskell, bit-manipulation, bytestring

In Haskell, it seems that bit-wise operations are typically handled via the [Data.Bits module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html) and the Bits class.

I'd like to perform bit-manipulations on ByteStrings of any length (eg set, clear, shift, masks...) but I cannot find an instance of Bits for ByteStrings anywhere.

My question: should I implement the instance myself (probably a good exercise)? If so is there any recommendation to get some "acceptable performance"? Or is it a bad idea to try to do bit-manipulations directly on ByteStrings, in which case what would be a better way?

Comment: For bitwise operations, you can use `zipWith` and the word level operation.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any reason why it would be a bad idea. If you wanted to be super-general you could implement

```
instance (Listlike l a, Bits a) => Bits (l a) where ...
```

This will give you a Bits implementation for any [list-like](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ListLike-4.5) type, which happens to [include Bytestrings](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ListLike-4.5/docs/Data-ListLike-Instances.html).

Comment: "I can't see any reason why it would be a bad idea" except if this is for a library. Don't put orphan instances like that in libraries.

Comment: Presumably the instance would look like `instance (ListLike l a, Bits a) => Bits l where ...`. But then you are overlapping literally every other instance of `Bits`. Probably not a good idea to do this in *that* particular way.

Comment: They're suggesting something like `newtype AggregateBits a = AggregateBits a` and I suggest using `FiniteBits` instead of `Bits` in the precondition,  Also, `l` is the full type for `Listlike`, not `l a`.  Altogether, `instance (Listlike l a, FiniteBits a) => Bits (AggregateBits l) where...`

Answer (score 0):

I found the [bits-bytestring](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bits-bytestring) package on Hackage providing what you ask for.

But I would be careful with some of the operations, if not all your bytestrings are of the same length. In particular, which bits are set by `complement` depends on the length of the bytestring.